# Azure AD B2C profile edit available options

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure AD and trying to setup and learn Azure AD B2C. I am able to run built in user flows and created custom policies to update user profiles. But Just wanted to check, if end users of my applications can edit their profile using https://myaccount.microsoft.com ? Or built-in user flows and custom policies in Identity Experience Framework are the only two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that link is for Azure AD, not B2C.

You have to use the B2C flows.